# How do I create an AWS Lambda layer for seaborn?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, matplotlib, aws-lambda, seaborn

I have been unsuccessful in creating a layer for seaborn to be used on AWS Lambda.

I have tried creating a python environment and installing seaborn using the following commands:

```
python -m venv python
cd python/Scripts
activate
pip3 install seaborn
```

The package installs, and then I organize the folder using this heirarchy:
`aws_lambda_python37_layer_seaborn\python\lib\python3.7\site-packages\seaborn`

(site-packages contains a number of other folders as well, which are dependencies of seaborn I assume)

I copied the heirarchy from a layer someone else created for matplotlib, which works correctly as a layer on AWS Lambda.

When I try to import seaborn however, I receive this error:
"errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'seaborn'"

I am using python 3.7

Comment: seaborn requires a lot of dependencies. I created the layer but it was over 70MB.  Are you using two layers to overcome the limit of 50 MB per layer?

Comment: I already have a working mathplotlib layer, which is a dependency of seaborn. Is that what you meant?

Comment: I can provide the steps for the seaborn layer, the way I would do it, but I would have to exclude its dependencies due to the total size. If this would be helpful, I could provide an answer with details.

Comment: Yes, please do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just **created the custom layer** with `seaborn` and can **confirm that it works**. The layer explicitly installs some dependencies, but not uses `numpy` and `scipy`. These two packages must be provided by AWS managed layer `AWSLambda-Python37-SciPy1x`.

Thus you need to use **two layers in your function**. One custom created below, and the second one is `AWSLambda-Python37-SciPy1x`.

The technique used includes **docker tool** described in the recent **AWS blog**:

- [How do I create a Lambda layer using a simulated Lambda environment with Docker?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-layer-simulated-docker/)

Thus for this question, I **verified it**  as follows:

1. Create empty folder, e.g. `mylayer`.

```
mkdir mylayer && cd mylayer
```

2. Go to the folder and create `requirements.txt`:

```
echo seaborn > requirements.txt 
echo matplotlib >> requirements.txt
echo pyparsing >> requirements.txt
echo cycler >> requirements.txt
echo certifi >> requirements.txt
echo pillow >> requirements.txt
echo six >> requirements.txt
echo pandas >> requirements.txt
echo kiwisolver >> requirements.txt
echo pytz >> requirements.txt
```

3. Run the following docker command:

Note the use of `--no-deps` to skip any dependencies appart
from those specified above.

```
docker run -v "$PWD":/var/task "lambci/lambda:build-python3.7" /bin/sh -c "pip install --no-deps -r requirements.txt -t python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/; exit"
```

4. Create layer as zip:

```
zip -9 -r mylayer.zip python
```

5. Create lambda layer based on `mylayer.zip` in the AWS Console.
   Don't forget to specify `Compatible runtimes` to `python3.7`.
6. Test the layer in lambda using the following lambda function:

```
import json

import seaborn

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    print(dir(seaborn))
```

The function **executes correctly**:

```
['FacetGrid', 'JointGrid', 'PairGrid', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', '__version__', '_orig_rc_params', 'algorithms', 'axes_style', 'axisgrid', 'barplot', 'blend_palette', 'boxenplot', 'boxplot', 'categorical', 'catplot', 'choose_colorbrewer_palette', 'choose_cubehelix_palette', 'choose_dark_palette', 'choose_diverging_palette', 'choose_light_palette', 'clustermap', 'cm', 'color_palette', 'colors', 'countplot', 'crayon_palette', 'crayons', 'cubehelix_palette', 'dark_palette', 'desaturate', 'despine', 'distplot', 'distributions', 'diverging_palette', 'dogplot', 'external', 'factorplot', 'get_data_home', 'get_dataset_names', 'heatmap', 'hls_palette', 'husl_palette', 'jointplot', 'kdeplot', 'light_palette', 'lineplot', 'lmplot', 'load_dataset', 'lvplot', 'matrix', 'miscplot', 'mpl', 'mpl_palette', 'pairplot', 'palettes', 'palplot', 'plotting_context', 'pointplot', 'rcmod', 'regplot', 'regression', 'relational', 'relplot', 'reset_defaults', 'reset_orig', 'residplot', 'rugplot', 'saturate', 'scatterplot', 'set', 'set_color_codes', 'set_context', 'set_hls_values', 'set_palette', 'set_style', 'stripplot', 'swarmplot', 'utils', 'violinplot', 'widgets', 'xkcd_palette', 'xkcd_rgb']
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer@Marcin, is there a way we could do this with `https://pypi.org/`, I have been trying to use xlrd

Comment: Thanks @Marcin, I have not posted this question hence unable to accept, but upvoted it, and I get `ImportError: Can't determine version for xlrd`, any help on this would be appreciated

Comment: @ If you make question specific to your issue, it would be better In my view. It would allow others to contribute as well and it would be easier for others to find it in the future. I try to help as well.

Comment: Thank you @Marcin! I appreciate your help!

Comment: @Marcin I finally had time to try your steps, but I quickly received this error:

[docker: error during connect: Post http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.40/containers/create: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified. In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running.]


Would it be possible to share the zip file you created?

Comment: @JoeCarter The steps work and are correct. But I used linux, not windows. The error message says that the docker daemon may be not running. Are you sure its running correctly? I can check how to share the layer.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer to my post works correctly for Linux, and works for Windows as well, with one small tweak.
For Windows users that stumble across this post, here is what I had to do to create my own layer:

The reason Docker was not running properly on my computer was caused by the version of Windows 10 I had. I had Windows 10 Home, and I needed Professional or Enterprise to run Docker properly. After I upgraded to Windows Professional I was able to properly install Docker.

With Docker properly installed, I was then able to run @Marcin's command.

But since this is for Windows, I needed to change "$PWD" to "%cd%".

Like this:
`docker run -v "%cd%":/var/task "lambci/lambda:build-python3.7" /bin/sh -c "pip install --no-deps -r requirements.txt -t python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/; exit"`

After running this command, you should instantly be prompted by docker to allow file access to the specified directory. Allow it to let the command complete.

Once the command completes, be sure to zip just the folder titled python. Since this is for Windows, I don't believe @Marcin's zip command will work. But any zipping software is sufficient. I used 7-Zip just fine. Right-click on the python folder, select "add to python.zip" and voila! your zipped layer is ready to be added to AWS Lambda.